# Implicit intents with startService are not safe InAppPurchase

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I've implemented In-app purchase in my application and I face this problem

> Implicit intents with startService are not safe: Intent { act=com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND }
>   android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService:538
>   com.bulbulapps.bulbul.v3.BillingProcessor.bindPlayServices:106
>   com.bulbulapps.bulbul.v3.BillingProcessor.:99

My code:

```
getContext().bindService(new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND"),  serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

but that line is generating a warning Implicit intents with startService are not safe.

Payment popup coming and payment also success, but after success it is not coming to OnActivity result

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {
        if (!bp.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data))
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onActivityResult", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

My requirement is I have to handle after successful purchase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
  Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");
  serviceIntent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
  bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Use explicit intent only to bind a service otherwise it will throw exception in Android 5.0 and above.

Before Android 5.0 also it is suggested to use explicit intent only to bind a service.

> The Context.bindService() method now requires an explicit Intent, and
>   throws an exception if given an implicit intent. To ensure your app is
>   secure, use an explicit intent when starting or binding your Service,
>   and do not declare intent filters for the service.

Check this behavior change [here](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0-changes.html#BindService).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, what i have to change in my code

Comment: I'm using libgdx and not android but also some android code, what is mServiceConn suppose to be?